# how can I find the convergence of the integral $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ , $ x \in (-1,1)$

Tags: integration, functions, convergence-divergence

I want to check the convergence of the integral 
$\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ , for $ x \in (-1,1)$ 
but i don't know what to do. Every theory I know it is not working. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't want to be silly... but you might want to use $1-x^n=(1-x)(1+\dots+x^{n-1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is a positive integer, then
$$\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=1+x+\dots+x^{n-1}$$

Comment: i already did that but couldn't figure out how to continue but i got an answer so thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well using division you have

> $${1-x^n\over 1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$$

Taking absolute values we see

$$\left|{1-x^n\over 1-x}\right|=\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^k\right|\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|x|^k\le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}1 = n$$

But then your integral converges because $$0\le \left|\int_{-1}^1{1-x^n\over 1-x}\,dx\right|\le \int_{-1}^1 n \,dx = 2n<\infty.$$

And absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: thank you so much,that actually works perfect in my problem

Comment: @NickRaven glad to help you find a comprehensible answer you can accept. If you find any of the answers here helpful you should upvote them, and accept the one you found most helpful if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{-1}^{1}x^k\,dx \stackrel{(i)}{=}2\sum_{j<\frac{n}{2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2j}\,dx=2\sum_{j<\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{2j+1}\tag{1}$$
where in $(i)$ we have exploited the fact that the integral of an odd, integrable function over a symmetric interval with respect to the origin is simply zero. Since $x\leq \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)$ for any $x\in[0,1)$,
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx =2+ 2\sum_{1\leq j<\frac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{2j+1}\leq 2+\sum_{1\leq j<\frac{n}{2}}\log\frac{2j+2}{2j}\leq \color{red}{2+\log( n+1)}\tag{2} $$
for any $n\geq 1$.

Comment: thank you, i will keep it in mind